# how to generate the .a file when creating static library iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I'm trying to create a static library in xcode 4, but i don't know how to generate the .a file. I added files to the library (.h .m) files, but when I run the the project the .a file is never generated. Do I have to do something special to generate this file? I'm following the steps in [this](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/15/how-to-create-universal-static-libraries-on-xcode-4/#comment-886)
tutorial.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd recommend building a universal framework instead.  It's way simpler:  http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/688

Answer (score 0):

The .a file was the product of the project file's target if memory serves.

It should show up under the "Products" group of the project navigator.  If it is not red, you can control-click it and choose "Show in Finder".

Comment: hi, I am trying to create static library but .a file under the product always getting red and not showing in finder. Can you halp me please, why happening this?